# Watch Flash movies with subtitles

Tags: subtitles, flash-video

There's a website that lets me watch streaming movies.

Is there a desktop app that could link to the Flash movie and accept subtitles also?

Comment: In what format are the subtitles? There are several popular formats. Or do you want to create subtitles yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the subtitles and **[Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/)**, a free subtitle editing program.

Follow the instructions at this post (and upvote the poster!):

> [Is there any software that can play a subtitle file without a video file?](https://superuser.com/questions/191319/is-there-any-software-that-can-play-a-subtitle-file-without-a-video-file/192551#192551)

Basically, you create a video-less subtitle player, and split your screen from the flash player and the subtitle player.  When ads come on, just simply pause the subtitles.  Pretty simple in the end...

Answer (score 1):

You can download the flash movie (there are many apps and Firefox extensions for this, even if the original site does not provide a direct d/l link). Then [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) can play the movie from the file. Mplayer lets you specify subtitles to be read from an extra file (option `-sub` and friends).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly this how to do it. But i use the following technique to enjoy both subtitle and the movie .

1. If in chrome get the URL of the video from console panel ( or from inspect element or from the third party soft like internet download manager )
2. Get the subtitle file of the movie u really needed, that is Google the subtitle file with    corresponding language and download it.
3. Now open VLC or any other media players and start watching the movie by pasting the URL (if in VLC u just need to hit Ctrl+v and paste the URL)
4. now add the previously downloaded subtitle file to the video player (if in VLC just right click and add through the subtitle option)

   so that's it, u can stream the movie along with the subtitles. I know this is not exactly how to add the subtitles to the flash player but this one is a good trick that always works .
   hope u liked it, if so please rate up the answer.

Regards,
Kayches.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but for those who may be interested and use Windows, there's software called [SubViewer](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/SubViewer.htm) (author of the format SubViewer as well as a friend of author of SubRip). It allows to show subs completely transparent and w/o GUI, although first you'll probably will need some software to make SubViewer stay on top of other windows while they're active (ATM can't remember any, but there's lots of them, just Google).

When you'll have all the software, launch SubViewer and go to `Main Menu > File > Open...` to load desired subtitle and `Main Menu > Options > Show Transparent Subtitle` to hide GUI.

The software itself is very simple and straightforward, so there shouldn't be any issues. To show the GUI again you have two choices:

- if there are no subs visible ATM, press `F5` to show menu, and disable
  transparency from there;
- if there are subs, then just double
  click on subtitle and the GUI will be visible once again.

BTW, it uses Net Framework, so you might want to install it if you haven't.